# glMultiDrawArraysIndirect does not work when specifying an offset

Tags: opengl, rendering

I'm trying to use `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect` to render a batch of object.

In my example I have a cube and a sphere **(in this order)** in a `VBO` and a `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER (SSBO)` that contains matrix transforms as well as a `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER (DIB)` that contains the draw commands.

The allocation of both the `SSBO` and `DIB` are managed by a custom class.

I can currently render both objects successfully, each using their own transform. The problem I'm encountering is rendering just the sphere by specifying an offset. As per the OpenGL spec:

> If a buffer is bound to the `GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` binding at the
>   time of a call to **glMultiDrawArraysIndirect**, *indirect* is interpreted
>   as an offset, in basic machine units, into that buffer and the
>   parameter data is read from the buffer rather than from client memory.

but doing the following code to render results in nothing being rendered:

```
// Calculates the offset & size and calls BindBufferRange 
this->_indrMatrixBuffer.BindBufferRange(0, 1, 1);
// A simple call to glBindBuffer, binding to GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER
this->_indrBuffer.BindBuffer();
// Render
glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, (void*)sizeof(DAICmd), 1, 0);
```

<sub>The `DAICmd` is a struct of four `unsigned int` (as per the [spec](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect.xhtml))</sub>

At first I though it might be my custom class but calling `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1, 0);` and keeping the matrix buffer offset renders the cube in the spheres position!

What am I missing to get this to work?

---

**Extra notes**

- Both the `SSBO` & `DIB` are mapped using the flags `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT, GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT and GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT` and are created with the same flags plus `GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT`
- I'm using OpenGL 4.5
- Using `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, (void*)sizeof(DAICmd), 1, 0);` does not produce an error when using `glGetError()`
- Using KHR_debug produces no errors either

Comment: Code looks right on a first glance. Are you checking for GL errors? Do you have [KHR_debug](http://renderingpipeline.com/2013/09/opengl-debugging-with-khr_debug/) output set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my class handling the population fo the `draw indirect commands`.

Each time I added a new command to the indirect buffer I also incremented the `baseInstance`, so the cube had `baseInstance = 0` and the sphere had `baseInstance = 1`.

The reason why it doesn't render the sphere is because `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect` pretty much evaluates as `glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance(mode,  cmd->first,  cmd->count,  cmd->instanceCount, cmd->baseInstance);` (as per the [OGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect)).

The drawID is calculated as `(gl_InstanceID / divisor) +`**`baseInstance`** ([link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance)), which means that the drawID is out of range when trying to render with an offset, as the sphere now appears as the first element in the indirect buffer.